# Speed difference between Linq to XML and Excel with a OledbConnection?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, excel, linq-to-xml

On e of my current requirements is to take in an Excel spreadsheet that the user updates about once a week and be able to query that document for certain fields.

As of right now, I run through and push all the Excel (2007) data into an xml file (just once when they upload the file, then I just use the xml) that then holds all of the needed data (not all of the columns in the spreadsheet) for querying via Linq-to-XML; note that the xml file is smaller than the excel.

Now my question is, is there any performance difference between querying an XML file with Linq and an Excel file with OledbConnection?  Am I just adding another unneccesary step?
I suppose the followup question would be, is it worth it for ease of use to keep pushing it to xml.

The file has about 1000 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something that is done only once per week I don't see the need to perform any optimizations. Instead you should focus on what is maintainable and understandable both for you and whoever will maintain the solution in the future.

Use whatever solution you find most natural :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the performance side of things stands like this for accessing Excel data.

Fastest to Slowest
1. Custom 3rd party vendor software using C++ directly on the Excel file type.
2. OleDbConnection method using a schema file if necessary for data types, treats Excel as a flatfile db.
3. Linq 2 XML method superior method for read/write data with Excel 2007 file formats only.
4. Straight XML data manipulation using the OOXML SDK and optionally 3rd party xml libraries. Again limited to Excel 2007 file formats only.
5. Using an Object[,] array to read a region of cells (using .Value2 prop), and passing an Object[,] array back again to a region of cells (again .Value2 prop) to write data.
6. Updating and reading from cells individually using the .Cells(x,y) and .Offset(x,y) prop accessors.

Comment: To further answer your question. Whilst there will be a small overall performance benefit to using OleDbConnection over linq2XML, the Linq code will be more maintainable and easier to write. Also the OleDbConnection code is more fragile and only really good when the region of data is static. With frequently updated dynamic data it can be quite challenging to program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a SqlConnection to access an Excel spreadsheet.  More than likely, you are using an OleDbConnection or an OdbcConnection.

That being said, I would *guess* that using the OleDbConnection to access the Excel sheet would be faster, as you are processing the data natively, but the only way to know for the data *you* are using is to test it yourself, using the Stopwatch class in the System.Diagnostics namespace, or using a profiling tool.

If you have a great deal of data to process, you might also want to consider putting it in SQL Server and then querying that (depending on the ratio of queries to the time it takes to save the data, of course).

Comment: woops, I fixed that in the question -- the xml file would be native too.  I will test with stopwatch.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to discuss what type of querying you are doing with the file.  I have to believe it will be a great deal easier to query using LINQ than the oledbconnection although I am talking more from experience than anything else.